# Teamviewer vpn install?

Tags: vpn, teamviewer

How can I install Team-viewer program for VPN feature? I dont see that option
I have Ubuntu studio, Here is my [screen-shot](https://plus.google.com/+Erzs%C3%B3kaCsuhajov%C3%A1/posts/dbC6K7hRZ3X?pid=6124181081993593858&oid=104657328721671509517) from Team-Viewer.

Comment: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The VPN functionality is not currently supported on Linux. They may have plans for it in the future, however.

**You may use windows version of Team Viewer via wine for VPN feature.**

Install wine :

Execute following commands in terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Then download teamviewer for windows, then run the setup using wine.

Comment: Did anyone try this? Did it work? Did you end up with some alternative?